# AWS Lambda Layer access issues caused by zip file permissions/settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I recently changed computers and now when I publish a layer my Lambda function cannot access it.  I get a "Cannot find module" error.  I've played around with permissions and file groups but cannot get it to work.

From my old computer this zip file works fine:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 myname  wheel     72086 Aug 29 08:37 shared_modules.zip
```

I tried the following from my new computer and none of the variants worked:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 myname  admin     72086 Aug 29 08:37 shared_modules.zip
-rw-r--r--    1 myname  everyone     72086 Aug 29 08:37 shared_modules.zip
-rw-r--r--    1 myname  staff     72086 Aug 29 08:37 shared_modules.zip
```

I cannot change the file group to wheel on my new computer because it does not exist.  My understanding is that wheel was removed sometime over the past two years.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The content of your zip get extracted to the /Opt directory in the function. Try extracting the zip and comparing their contents/ permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the layers as @keithRozario suggested. the answer was pretty simple.  Although I had changed the permissions of the root directory, I had not changed the permissions of the sub-directories.  They all had drwxr--r--@, which shows up as 'custom' in the Get Info panel on a Mac and needed drwxr-xr-x@, which is Read Only.

Thanks, @keithRozario, for the suggestion.